# Visual studio debugging view last statement in method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I'd like to know how to debug the last statement in a method? For example, let's say I have the following statement method:

```
private void doSomething()
{
  int x = 5;
  int y = x + 4;
  int z = y * 2;
}
```

If I but the breakpoint at the start of the method and step trough the method, I can see the result of x, the result of y, but not the result of z, how can I see the result of z while debugging?

EDIT: Apparently this value is being skipped because it isn't significant to the program but while it might not be significant for the final program but it is significant while debugging & testing and highly annoying when I have to add dummy statements for these kind of things.

Comment: If you aren't doing anything with `z` then its value is not significant.  If that value is being returned, assigned to a property on a parameter, or assigned to an out / ref parameter, then why not inspect that value after the method executes.

Comment: @cardell0 It might not be significant for the final program but it is significant while debugging & testing and highly annoying when I have to add dummy statements for these kind of things.

Comment: The point I was trying to make was in a simple example like this, the value of z never matters.  In a real world scenario, there might be better ways to view this value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a breakpoint at the closing bracket `}`. `z` should be available there. Or you could multiply `y` by 2...

Comment: @NomenNescio are you debugging in release mode?

Comment: Debugging. If it works for you but doesn't work for me then it's probably some setting...

Comment: @NomenNescio I know you're debugging, but have you built in release or debug mode? You can also debug in release mode.

Comment: Well it says "Debugging" next to the green arrow so I think that's what you mean right?

Comment: @NomenNescio no. I'm talking about the build configuration.

Comment: Ah, found it. I had to change the configuration for the project, apparently there is a configuration for the solution & project are separate things.

Comment: @NomenNescio yes. If in release, the compiler can optimize code, so it may be that some variables are excluded alltogether.

Answer (score 0):

Once you're debugging and code-processing halts, **right-click** on 'z' (or whatever variable you want to observe) and **select  "Add Watch"**.

This should open up a 'Watch' tab where you can observe what happens to any values you have an interest in, step-by-step and line-by-line.

Comment: `z` isn't available until the last line before `}`.